# convert multidimensional html form data to json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form with several textboxes. I want to serialize the whole form to json in a way that those text boxes remains in an array. I have the following html

```
<form id ="myform">
    <input type="text" name="options[]"/>
    <input type="text" name="options[]"/>
    <input type="text" name="options[]"/>
    <input type="text" name="options[]"/>
</form>
```

And I use jquery to convert it to json

```
JSON.stringify($("#myform").serializeArray());
```

This gives me the following:

```
  {
    "options[]":"Content of the last textbox"
  }
```

but I want

```
  {
   "options":
             {
              "0":"value",
              "1":"value",
              "2":"value",
              "3":"value",
             }
  }
```

How can I achieve this using javascript?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't give you that all-> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/knnsb0vt/** , it gives you an array in the proper format for an ajax request in form-www-urlencoded.

Comment: "Content of the last checkbox"? But you're using text fields.

Comment: `serializeArray` won't help with this. You have to build that json manually

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JS object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Comment: I have updated my answer which I hope is a better solution now to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = $("#myform").serializeArray();
var result = {"objects":{}};
arr.forEach(function (elem, i) {
    result.objects[i] = elem["value"];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelortega/oy2vjm7m/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done manually with jQuery `serializeArray()` as an aid

```
var serializedArray = $('#myform').serializeArray();
var customArray = {};
customArray['options'] = {};
for(key in serializedArray)
{
    customArray['options'][key] = serializedArray[key]['value'];
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8we11h1n/3/)

Comment: Are you suggesting `serializeArray` doesn't handle names with `[]` ? The two methods should be the same, but one returns a querystring, the other an array ?

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. It doesn't really solve the question at all

Comment: @adeneo, you are right, I have updated my answer. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#myform").submit(function(event){
            var foo=$(this).serializeArray();
            var option={"option":foo};

            console.log(JSON.stringify(option));
            return false;
        });


    });


      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i came across this question after I solved the same problem my self. 
I searched everywhere for a solution and it feels like i'm missing something basic (either javascript/jquery or .net MVC) that would do this for me. 
But this is how I eventually managed to solve a similar problem to yours.

```js
    var serializeForm = function (form) {
        var result = [];
        var buildArray = function m(name, value) {
            var match = name.match(/\[\d+\]/);
            if (!match) {
                var ret = {};
                ret[name] = value;
    
                return ret;
            } else {
                var ret = {};
                var thisName = name.slice(0, match.index);
                var index = match[0].match(/\d+/)[0];
    
                ret[thisName] = m(name.slice(match.index + match[0].length + 1), value);
                ret.index = index;
                return ret;
            }
        };
    
        $.each(form, function (i, o) {
            result.push(buildArray(o.name, o.value));
        });
    
        var json = {};
        var buildObject = function m(json, o) {
            var indexKey = 'index';
            for (var key in o) {
                if (key != indexKey) {
                    if (o.hasOwnProperty(indexKey)) {
                        if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            json[key] = [];
                        }
    
                        if (!json[key].hasOwnProperty(o[indexKey])) {
                            json[key][o[indexKey]] = {};
                        }
    
                        json[key][o[indexKey]] = m(json[key][o[indexKey]], o[key]);
                    } else {
                        json[key] = o[key];
                    }
                }
            }
            return json;
        }
        $.each(result, function (i, o) {
            buildObject(json, o);
        });
        return json;
    }
    
    $(function(){
      console.log(serializeForm($('form').serializeArray()));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input name="low[0].mid[0].high" value="0 0" type="text" />
  <input name="low[0].mid[1].high" value="0 1" type="text" />
  <input name="low[1].mid[0].high" value="1 0" type="text" />
  <input name="low[1].mid[1].high" value="1 1" type="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: I realize it only partially answers your question. And my problem was different than yours. But maybe you can modify it to solve yours?